# angularjs ui-router persistant page elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to get my head around angularjs and ui-router at the moment, my application is split into 3 layouts basically (Marketing Layout, Authentication Layout & Application Layout). I am currently struggling to get my ui-router working to allow me to do this, I understand that I can have parent states that are abstracted (correct?) but I am struggline to get child states to inherit parent views etc.

Basically what I wanting to do is the following - I'll use the application section of the site for the example.

A user is logged in logged, and the screen is split into a header, sidebar, and main content area, where the ever the user goes within applicaiton section of the site, the header and sidebar will remain but the main contnet will update to the relevant content. Here is what I have so far

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/application/dashboard');

$stateProvider
    .state('application', {
        abstract : true,
        views : {
            '@' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/layout.html',
                controller : 'applicationController'
            },
            'top@index' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/app/header.html'
            },
            'left@index' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/app/sidebar.html'
            },
            'main@index' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/app/main.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('application.dashboard', {
        url : '/application/dashboard',
        views : {
            '@' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/schools/manage.html',
                controller : ''
            },
            'main@app' : {
                templateUrl : ''
            }
        }
    })
```

}]);

https://plnkr.co/edit/6fJNjTFhoKqyN82P7NvL?p=preview

As you will able to see I can see the manage.html template, but on the preview I should also see the page header from the header.html template, and the sidebar.html also...

Any ideas as to why I am not? I assume it is something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you basically want an app skeleton of Header, Sidebar and MainContent. The only thing that should change is MainContent. The contents of the header or sidebar may change, but they'll be persistent.

I personally think router should have nothing to do with this; a router should route. Having it be a data bus and application state manager seems to tightly couple things that shouldn't be.

Anyway, with that said, here's how I go about it. In my index.html, here's my markup:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div header-directive></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div footer-directive></div>
</body>
```

That's it. If you have other elements and need them to be responsive, just use a bootstrap grid (like to lay in sidebars or whatever). If you don't have to worry about any of that, a good ol' simple html table does the job perfectly. You can use CSS to do fixed positioning, height, etc.

With this setup, your header and footer never go away, and the router will only change the content in the ng-view. You use the router for the one and only thing that the term "router" makes sense for: routing from here, to there. Here's a sample router config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', ...

        function ( $routeProvider, ... ) {

            $routeProvider.

                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    controllerAs: 'homeCtl'
                })

                .when('/info', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/info.html',
                    controller: 'InfoController',
                    controllerAs: 'infoCtl'
                })

                ....
```

For communication between the three components, you can just create a service that they all inject. This way you can send any one of the elements (or all of them) instructions to change their content, hide/show themselves, whatever you need.

Angular does sometimes drastically overcomplicate something simple. This is definitely one of them. The Router in Angular 2 is a complicated behemoth.